# Eclipse import replaced existing files. How to restore?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using eclipse neon and SVN Superversion. I did an accidental import for an existing project set and then selected yes-to-all option. That replaced my local version of the project with one from repo. I lost all my local changes. There is even no local history for the files. I think that is because the project folders were recreated overwriting existing ones. Any work around, beside file recovery apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that eclipse keeps a history even for the deleted files / projects. The history is in the location: `[myworkspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history`

Searching then location using **notepad++** ***find in files*** functionality with some ***key search words*** from the lost files / classes solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project or package and select `Restore from Local History...`.

Comment: No restore points available. I think that's because the import overwritten the whole project!

Comment: I'm sorry about that.